# I want to disable other bottoms after I click once

Tags: android, kotlin

i am working on QuizApp and I get a problem when I choose an answer and click submit it show me the correct and wrong answer and then I should click submit again to go to the next question, i want to disable that , I want when someone click submit he cant change the answer or choose another answer

here is my code

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    when (v?.id) {

        R.id.tv_option_one -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_one, 1)
        }

        R.id.tv_option_two -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_two, 2)
        }

        R.id.tv_option_three -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_three, 3)
        }

        R.id.tv_option_four -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_four, 4)
        }

        R.id.btn_submit -> {

            if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0) {

                mCurrentPosition++

                when {

                    mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {

                        setQuestion()
                    }
                    else -> {

                        // TODO (STEP 5: Now remove the toast message and launch the result screen which we have created and also pass the user name and score details to it.)
                        // START
                        val intent =
                            Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, mUserName)
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.CORRECT_ANSWERS, mCorrectAnswers)
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, mQuestionsList!!.size)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                        // END
                    }
                }
            } else {
                val question = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)

                // This is to check if the answer is wrong
                if (question!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition) {
                    answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    //

                }
                else {
                    mCorrectAnswers++
                }

                // This is for correct answer
                answerView(question.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)

                if (mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size) {
                    btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
                } else {
                    btn_submit.text = "GO TO NEXT QUESTION"
                }

                mSelectedOptionPosition = 0
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun setQuestion() {

    val question = mQuestionsList!!.get(mCurrentPosition - 1) // Getting the question from the list with the help of current position.

    defaultOptionsView()

    if (mCurrentPosition == mQuestionsList!!.size) {
        btn_submit.text = "FINISH"
    } else {
        btn_submit.text = "SUBMIT"
    }

    progressBar.progress = mCurrentPosition
    tv_progress.text = "$mCurrentPosition" + "/" + progressBar.getMax()

    tv_question.text = question.question
    iv_image.setImageResource(question.image)
    tv_option_one.text = question.optionOne
    tv_option_two.text = question.optionTwo
    tv_option_three.text = question.optionThree
    tv_option_four.text = question.optionFour
}

/**
 * A function to set the view of selected option view.
 */
private fun selectedOptionView(tv: TextView, selectedOptionNum: Int) {

    defaultOptionsView()

    mSelectedOptionPosition = selectedOptionNum

    tv.setTextColor(
        Color.parseColor("#363A43")
    )
    tv.setTypeface(tv.typeface, Typeface.BOLD)
    tv.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        this,
        R.drawable.selected_option_border_bg
    )
}

/**
 * A function to set default options view when the new question is loaded or when the answer is reselected.
 */
private fun defaultOptionsView() {

    val options = ArrayList<TextView>()
    options.add(0, tv_option_one)
    options.add(1, tv_option_two)
    options.add(2, tv_option_three)
    options.add(3, tv_option_four)

    for (option in options) {
        option.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A8089"))
        option.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT
        option.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.default_option_border_bg
        )
    }
}

/**
 * A function for answer view which is used to highlight the answer is wrong or right.
 */
private fun answerView(answer: Int, drawableView: Int) {

    when (answer) {

        1 -> {
            tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                drawableView
            )
        }
        2 -> {
            tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                drawableView
            )
        }
        3 -> {
            tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                drawableView
            )
        }
        4 -> {
            tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                drawableView
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whenever a question loads, you can use `isEnabled` property on the submit button and answer options to enable/disable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your onclick, change the other views

```
view.isClickable = false
```